# Leetcode | Return result is always empty

Tags: javascript

I'm going over some array problems on Leetcode and when I tried to submit my answer I got an empty result as my answer. I'm not sure why it's happing. I tried to run this function in Chrome DevTools and it works as expected. Any hints would be appreciated.

[image]

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {number}
 */
function removeDuplicates(nums) {
    return nums.filter((n, index) => nums[index] != nums[++index])
}
```

Link to the problem: https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-easy/92/array/727/

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Here's the link: https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-easy/92/array/727/

Comment: the code seems to work on my end.. either way ur code wouldn't solve all problems with that logic ;-;

Comment: bruh i think u shud take it up with leetcode cuz this is super strange

Comment: Did anything come of this? I having the same issue on leetcode.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is strange because I went and even logged to the `console.log` my correct answer but the return is.. very strange.. so far it seems that this is *not* your fault

I even tried making the return be a string and it still shows this empty array.. it's strange FOR REAL

[image]

Comment: Indeed, it's super strange. Thanks for confirming it. I already reported this issue to the Leetcode helpdesk. I hope, they'll get back to me asap.

Answer (score 0):

Is `nums` unsorted? If so, you'd need to do something like this:

```
function removeDuplicates(nums) {
    const set = new Set();

    return nums.filter(n => {
        if (!set.has(n)) {
            set.add(n);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });
}
```

Otherwise, if sorted, your solution seems right.

Comment: the error isn't his code.. it's that the return is an empty array no matter what you return ;-;

Comment: well according to the code question.. it asks to `remove the duplicates in-place` so sorting the answer array isn't necessary.. however if u just clicked the link and read at the very beginning it says `Given an integer array nums sorted in non-decreasing order`

Comment: Link didn’t work for me, so I didn’t see that. That’s why I asked if nums was unsorted or not.